# Embedded DisplayPort to DisplayPort converter cable

Tags: display-port

I am looking for an embedded DisplayPort (eDP) to DisplayPort (DP) cable to connect an eDP output to a monitor with DP input. Resolution of video is 4K.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: 
I have found an eDP to DP cable pinmap.

- Is just mapping the pins enough ?
- Are there any other variables to consider, like power supply ?
- Will there be a loss in quality depending on the length of cable ?

[image: eDP to DP cable pin-map]

Comment: I'm finding lots of stuff to go the other way, to use an eDP panel with a regular DP input. I can't find any ready-to-use product that does the other direction. I *am* finding several DIY discussions about wiring an eDP output into a DP input; It is possible and only a specific subset of pins need to be connected for the video signal. eDP has a lot of other functionality that DP does not.

Comment: @Romen Thanks for your reply. 

I have found an eDP to DP cable pinout (Edited the question to add the image). Is just mapping the pins enough ? Are there any other variables to consider, like power supply ? Will there be a loss in quality depending on the length of cable ? 

Also, can you provide the link to the DIY discussions you found ?

Comment: What board are you using that has eDP out? Most boards I know have DPI or DSI.

Comment: I'm looking for the same kind of cable/adapter. Have you made any progress by any chance?